# Radon-Nikodem Derivative of a purely nonatomic Borel Measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $\mu$ is a purely non-atomic Borel measure on a topological space $X$ then must its density be a continous function to $\mathbb{R}$?

My intuition says yes because all my counterexamples are not diffuse....

Important definitions:

**Density:** 
If $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $X$ then $\mu$'s density is a measurable function $g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying: for every Borel subset $B$ of $X$ $\mu(B)=\int I_B g dm$ (where $m$ is Lebesgue measure).

Comment: Could you give the definition of the density function of $\mu$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by density.

Comment: So $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: No, for example I can take a projection from an infinite dimensional Banach space onto $\mathbb{R}$ to be my density...

Comment: You also need to say what is the "Lebesgue measure" in your definition when $X$ is not eulidean space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)**
In $\mathbb R$, let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0,1]$.  Then the density
$$
h(x) = \begin{cases}
1,\qquad 0 \le x \le 1\\
0,\qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is not continuous.

**(b)**
In $\mathbb R^2$, let $\mu$ be "arc length" measure on a circle.  It is nonatomic.  But it has no density (continuous or not) with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer :)